# Read Pubsub message to read from Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I would like to read a BigQuery table based on the content of a pubsub message

```py
subscription = 'my_subscription'

tablename = (p
              | 'receive msg from PubSub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=subscription)
              | "convert msg to dict" >> beam.Map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
              | "extract tablename" >> beam.Map(lambda x: x['tablename'])
             )
(p
  | 'Read from BQ Table' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(table=tablename)
  | #more transformations...     )
```

Deploying this to a template_metadata file yields the following error message:

*"TypeError: expected string or buffer"*

Answer (score 2):

The `readFromPubSub` `IO` returns a `PubSubMessage` object.

If you want to retrieve the data inside the `PubSubMessage` object, you have to change your code as follow :

```py
subscription = 'my_subscription'

tablename = (p
              | 'receive msg from PubSub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=subscription)
              | "convert msg to dict" >> beam.Map(lambda msg: json.loads(msg.data.decode()))
              | "extract tablename" >> beam.Map(lambda x: x['tablename'])
             )
(p
  | 'Read from BQ Table' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(table=tablename)
  | #more transformations...     )
```

I changed the transformation from `PubSubMessage` to `Dict` :
`json.loads(msg.data.decode())`

The `msg.data.decode` allows to retrieve the data as `str`, then the `json.loads` will convert it correctly to `Dict`.

Your last transformation should normally work well and you could retrieve the `tablename` from the `Dict`.